# Nested Spark Row in case class for dealing with data that has variable types?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to figure out a way to model collections of data with variable type in a Scala case class that I manipulate as a Spark Dataset.

Is it possible to nest a Spark Row in a case class like the following? Is there a better way to model a collection of data that has variable type (e.g., I thought about `Map[String,Any]` but `Any` won't work because you need an encoder for the value)?

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

case class A(a: String, row: Row)

val a = A("this", Row.apply(1, "this", true))

Seq(a).toDS
```

If so, what's the best way to specify the Encoder needed given the error I'm getting with executing the above code.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for org.apache.spark.sql.Row
- field (class: "org.apache.spark.sql.Row", name: "row")
- root class: "A"
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:643)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:445)
  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:824)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:445)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1$$anonfun$8.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:637)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1$$anonfun$8.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:625)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:625)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:445)
  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:824)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:445)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:434)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:71)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.LowPrioritySQLImplicits$class.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:34)
  ... 48 elided
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-RowEncoder.html. This should solve your issue.

Comment: I tried to create a StructType that mimics the structure of my case class A, and then turned it into an encoder with the RowEncoder you recommended. However, I get a `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.datacube.experimental.A cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row` when I try that. I'm thinking I probably should just convert the whole thing to a Row instead.